# JavaFX TableView selectAll is unusably slow

Tags: javafx

I just found out that JavaFX TableView selection model `selectAll()`-method is extremely slow when the table has enough data - I did not have patience to wait how long it takes for 50000 rows.

Anyone have any workaround ideas on how to select all items at once?

Failing that, TableView by default has `Ctrl+A` enabled for selecting all its rows. How would I go on disabling this shortcut?

Here's sample code to demonstrate the slowness, just press `Ctrl+A`:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    TableView<String> table = new TableView<>();

    table.getColumns().add(new TableColumn<>("first"));
    table.getColumns().add(new TableColumn<>("second"));
    table.getColumns().add(new TableColumn<>("third"));

    table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

    ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
        byte[] array = new byte[10];
        new Random().nextBytes(array);
        String generatedString = new String(array, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        data.add(generatedString);
    }
    table.setItems(data);

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(table);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: it's a bug, no hack around afaik

Comment: I do not experience any delay at all when selecting all, unless I hit Ctrl-A again. Then the app hangs for quite some time... definitely sounds like a bug, as @kleopatra says.

Answer (score 1):

I do not experience the same behaviour that you described. Changing your example size from 50.000 to 500.000 adds a slight delay between the key stroke and the UI update. Maybe this issue is CPU/Ram related? I'm running your example on following specs

OS: Win10 - CPU: Intel i7-6700 - RAM: 16GB - Java: Oracle JDK 1.8.0_162.

To answer your question nonetheless, you can register a key [EventHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/EventHandler.html) to be notified about key presses (or ups/downs). If the event describes Ctrl+A, call [consume](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/Event.html#consume--) to stop it from being propagated to further listeners (the table itself).

```
table.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
  if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.A && event.isControlDown()) {
    event.consume();
  }
});
```

Comment: Well, I have a relatively low-end laptop but that shouldn't really matter. My OS is Win10, and I'm running on OpenJDK 11 & OpenJFX 11. I tried that exact code to disable Ctrl+A earlier, but it doesn't seem to work...?

Comment: if you are prepared to go dirty, you can remove the short-cut from the table's inputMap, accessible via the behavior as defined by TableViewSkin. Accessing the behavior reflectively is the dirty part.

Comment: You probably need a event filter instead of an event handler to consume the event.

Comment: You may be able to recreate the issue by selecting all twice, ie: press Ctrl-A twice. The first time worked fine for me, second trigger crashed the application.